# Gamma always too high during Windows 10 color calibration

Tags: windows, windows-10, display, gamma

I'm using a TV monitor (an old memorex MLT1931, 19", if it matters) as a second monitor. I am using it with the same resolution as my other monitor (1920x1080), and its native resolution is 1280x720. Some of the colors are off, and my radeon advanced settings didn't seem to do much, and now I'm just doing the normal Windows 10 color calibration.

The issue I'm running into is that during the "adjust gamma" step, no matter how high or low the slider is, the image to the right of the slider always look like the "gamma too high" example, with a darker dot in the middle ([like in this photo](http://cdn.windowsreport.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/color-calibrate-wind8apps-e1431384160400.png)). The rest of the screen gets brighter/darker, but the dots stay the same.

When I switch the calibration window to my good monitor, the gamma is fine and I can see the dots adjust from bright to dark as I move the slider.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Possibly because it expects limited color range (16-235) but Radeon/Catalyst always outputs full color range (0-255).